# git svn rebase problem on windows

Tags: windows, svn, git, cygwin, msysgit

I have a problem with git.

Basically, here is what I have. I access a svn repository through git. Until now, on python files, everything worked fine.

But lately I also added some pyd, dll and lib files on the repository. THe first update went well. But then, these files have been modified and since then I can't update. These files were added from a windows computer with TortoiseSvn on the svn repository.

If I do a git svn rebase on linux, everything works fine.

If I do a git svn rebase on windows with msysgit (and also tortoisegit), I have the following error : **fatal: write error: Invalid argument**

If I do a git svn rebase on windows with cygwin, I have the following error : **didn't find newline after blob at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10/Git.pm line 916**

I tried several stuff (autocrlf true/false, safecrlf true/false), adding .gitattributes file with the following line *.* -crlf -diff -merge and nothing worked.

I'm a little stuck here so any suggestion would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: oh, and I also try git svn fetch -rHEAD and still the same problem

Comment: Others smarter than me will solve your actual problem.  But can I ask if these generated objects are generated by your project, or did they come from outside your project?  I'm curious why you have a need to put generated objects in the repository.

Comment: In fact, these generated objects are generated by someone else.
In short, everybody use python except one person. This person rewrite some of our python libraries in c++ in order to improve the speed. So he is the only one who adds the generated files in the repository and we don't need to recompile the c++ libraries on each computer.

Comment: What are the chances of sucking the source code into the repository and letting the generated files be... well, generated whenever you need them?

Comment: We can't do that cause some artists are working with the repository version. And trust me, you don't want to let an artist generate the files himself ;).

Answer (score 3):

Had identical issue with Msysgit v1.7.2.3, the latest version as at 29 Sep 10, and wanted to share my findings here (Google turns up several cases, but no solutions).

Trying to do "git svn rebase" on a repo (that has this has worked on plenty of times in the past) consistently failed with a "fatal: write error: Invalid argument" after a certain number of commits. The sync would then revert to the beginning again.

I believe this is a bug in Msysgit relating to large(ish) binaries and available memory (on a Win XP SP3 system with 4GB RAM and plenty free HD space). The remote system was the DotNetNuke SVN repo on CodePlex (https://dotnetnuke.svn.codeplex.com/svn).

Initially it was choking on a 330KB "CHM" file (~212th commit, r52261). It consistently did so, even after disabling Avast AV, Google Desktop, etc and verifying that there were no other processes with locks on the repo folder. After a reboot (but opening Outlook, Dreamweaver, etc), it then was consistently and repeatedly failing on a ~15.3MB DLL (~416th commit, same revision).

Finally, after another reboot, disabling Avast, Carbonite and Google Desktop and running no other programs, the sync worked first time.

This seems to point firmly to my conclusion that it was an available memory issue, probably linked to the presence of a largish binary and large number of commits in the revision. Note that I also tried "git fsck", "git svn reset xx" and tweaking the "packSizeLimit" / "usedeltabaseoffset" config vars, without success.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the best policy for using Git on windows is to tell it to not do anything about line endings.

I don't know if that will help you recover your current git repo, but it's worth a shot.

I set:

```
[core]
    autocrlf = false
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried autocrlf and safecrlf with either true or false and it's not working.